# Writing to the /sys/ folder on Android tablet

Tags: android, file-handling

I have an Android app with System permissions (it is installed in the priv-apps folder as part of a custom ROM).

The app has every possible permission in the manifest.

It is running on an Android 5.1 tablet that is NOT rooted and cannot be rooted.

I need to create a file under the **/sys/** directory, but have had no luck with various things that I have tried.

These include:

**1. Ensuring that the folder is writable**

```
    File dir = new File ("//sys/class/power_supply/battery");
    dir.setWritable(true);
```

It doesn't error but dir.canWrite() returns false.

**2. Programmatically calling chmod**

```
    public int chmod(File path, int mode) throws Exception {

    Log.e("DisableCharging.chmod",  "Starting");

    try {

        Class fileUtils = Class.forName("android.os.FileUtils");
        Method setPermissions =
                fileUtils.getMethod("setPermissions", String.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);
        return (Integer) setPermissions.invoke(null, path.getAbsolutePath(), mode, -1, -1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("DisableCharging.chmod",  "Error: " + e.toString());
        return  -1;
    }
```

Calling chmod(dir, 0777); results in:

```
W/FileUtils: Failed to chmod(/sys/class/power_supply/battery): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**3. Writing to file by shell command**

```
    String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "echo 0 > /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled"};
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Doesn't work, but doesn't throw any errors. (I am monitoring logcat via Android Studio).

**4. Writing to file via OutputStream**

```
File dir = new File ("//sys/class/power_supply/battery");
File file = new File(dir, "charging_enabled");
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
stream.write("0".getBytes());
stream.close();
```

Throws the following error when creating the output stream (line 3)

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**5. Writing to file using PrintWriter**

```
PrintWriter writer=null;
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream (new File(f));  // 2nd line
writer=new PrintWriter(os);
writer.print(s);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Same error as in 4. (obviously) as it can't open the OutputStream.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/power_supply/battery/charging_enabled: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**The Question(s)**

1. Is there any way to create a file and write to it under the **/sys/** folder?
2. If it's a folder permissions problem how can I grant those permissions?

*To re-iterate: This is a SYSTEM app with all permissions in the manifest on an Android 5.1 device that cannot be rooted.*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The method Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String) simply treats the input string as a file name of an executable. It won't accept your echo command. You should use the Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[]) instead, like:

> String[] cmd = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "echo xxx > /sys/somefile", };
>
> Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Alternatively, to write something to a sys file, you should use java.io.PrintWriter class.

Comment: Thanks for replying, however, I have tried both of these (please see the code examples in the original post).